# Batch Script : How to add timestamp before every line of log?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm new to batch scripting and I'm trying to create something where I can see the terminal output and log using Tee-Object.

Here's the working code :

```
powershell %* ^| tee-object -Append -FilePath "something.log"
```

However I'm looking to add timestamps before appending to the log file and unable to find any such script.

Here's the equivalent working code in shell script:

```
$* | while read line; do echo $line; echo "$(date) $line" >> something.log; done
```

Comment: I guess I have to ask, if you are not using `TEE` in your `SH` script why would you try to use it in `PowerShell`.  You are not attempting to do the same thing.  Your `SH` script is doing two echo commands. One with and one without the date.

Comment: `%* | foreach-object {$_;$(Get-Date).ToString() + ' ' + $_ | Out-File -append something.log}`

Comment: I could give you a pure batch file solution but would need to have more context as to what the value of `%*` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is text lines, you can add a timestamp with:

```
%* ^| ForEach-Object { $(Get-Date).ToString() + ' ' + $_ } ^| Tee-Object ...
```

`Tee-Object`, like `tee` on UNIX/Linux, is designed to send the same stream to two places. Without using `Tee-Object`, one could write to two different streams.

```
if (Test-Path -Path '.\teetime.log') { Remove-Item -Path '.\teetime.log' }
@('now','is','the','time') |
    ForEach-Object {
        $(Get-Date).ToString() + ' ' + $_ |
            Out-File -FilePath '.\teetime.log' -Encoding ascii -Append
        Write-Host $_
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works but may I know if I can add timestamp only to log file but not console ?

Comment: @BipinKumarRachaputi, `Tee-Objects` writes the same data to two streams. However, you can write separately as shown in the second example.

Comment: @BipinKumarRachaputi, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much.. However I figured this is working for me : %* ^| ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ ; $output_file =$(Get-Date).ToString() + ' ' + $_ ; Write-Output $output_file ^| Out-File -FilePath something.log -Append -NoClobber}

Comment: @BipinKumarRachaputi, I am glad you have something working. Your working code is similar to my second example, but with less lines of code.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for giving the foundation code